# JPA FetchType.LAZY collection is fetched during JSON serialization

Tags: spring, rest, jpa, spring-boot

The oneToMany annotated Collection is fetched during a rest call to the corresponding controller endpoint. the collection is a lazy fetch list
How can I avoid that collection from being fetched?
That is  a typically large collection and should not be wired unless explicitly requested.

thanks in advance.

```
    package xxx;

        import java.math.BigDecimal;
        import java.util.Calendar;
        import java.util.List;

        @Entity(name = "Ortaklik")
        // @Table(name="ortaklik",uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"id"})})
        @NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "Ortaklik.findMaxOrtaklik", query = "SELECT o FROM Ortaklik o WHERE o.id=(SELECT MAX(o.id) FROM o WHERE o.ortak.id=:ortakid )") })
        @JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class,property="@ortaklikId")

        public class OrtaklikEntity {

            @Id
            @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "seq_Ortaklik")
            @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "seq_Ortaklik", name = "seq_Ortaklik")
            private Long id;
            @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
            @JoinColumn(name = "ortak_id")
            @JsonBackReference
            private OrtakEntity ortak;
/**********************THIS IS THE MENTIONED COLLECTION****///////
            @OneToMany(mappedBy="ortaklik",fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
            private List<OngorulenAidatOdemePlanTaksitEntity> aidatList;

            public OrtaklikEntity() {
            }


            public List<OngorulenAidatOdemePlanTaksitEntity> getAidatList() {
                return aidatList;
            }

            public void setAidatList(List<OngorulenAidatOdemePlanTaksitEntity> aidatList) {
                this.aidatList = aidatList;
            }




        }

The inverse side of the relationship is as follows

    public class OngorulenAidatOdemePlanTaksitEntity implements Serializable, Comparable {

        // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="alanlar">
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "seq_ongrln_aidat_oplani_tkst")
        @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "seq_ongrln_aidat_oplani_tkst", name = "seq_ongrln_aidat_oplani_tkst")
        private Long id;

        @ManyToOne 
        @JoinColumn(name="ortaklik_id")
        private OrtaklikEntity ortaklik;
```

Comment: I dont think transient would help since these are already persisted records.  Unless the clients explicitly requests that collection (That is what lazy fetch is for) they should not be retrieved. If the client wishes to list the collection they should be wired to the client

Comment: I deleted my Transient suggestion because it was indeed bad. ;( Perhaps [@JsonIgnore](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnore.html) would work better instead?

Comment: It is explicitly called due to serialization. All properties (yes ALL properties) are serialized by default. If you don't want this create a DTO, or put `@JsonIgnore` on the field or use a `@JsonView` to specify what to expose.

Comment: Why isn't your transaction closed when you serialize the entity? Make sure your transaction is closed and everything should be fine.

Comment: M.Denium 's answer did the trick for me. First I disabled opensessioninview filter in application.properties then I JsonIgnored the child collection.If you post your reply , I 'd like to mark it as correct answer